# Show ProgressBar till EditText content changes

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Could anybody tell me, how can I set a ProgressBar in Android, which is shown till the content of an EditText changes? Because I have made an app, which loads some text through Bluetooth into an EditText, and this loading takes sometimes just a second, but many times up to 10 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a textChange listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the Progressbar when the EditText fires the corresponding `textchanged event`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

**Better:** Do not hide the ProgressBar when the EditText changes, but when your Bluetooth event is fired.